# Why I got error: Cannot query field xx on type "Query"?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Although I copied and pasted the graphQL query from the GraphiQL tool after I tested it at GraphiQL successfully , the query returned with an error when I tried it in Apollo client within a reactJS app:

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Cannot query field "allStudents" on type "Query"., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined
```

Here is my implementation:

```
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql',
  fetchOptions: { method: "POST" }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: link 
});

const GET_STUDENTS = gql`
query getStudents($schoolID: Int!){
  allStudents(schoolId: $schoolID){
    pickUpLat
    pickUpLng
  }
}
`;

client
  .query({
    query: GET_STUDENTS,
    variables: { schoolID: 1 }
  })
  .then(result => console.log(result));
```

What could be wrong? here is the correct response that I expected:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allStudents": [
      {
        "pickUpLat": 31.9752942479727,
        "pickUpLng": 35.8438429235775
      },
      {
        "pickUpLat": 31.9754545979993,
        "pickUpLng": 35.8437478537235
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
I get expected results using GraphiQL:
[image]

**EDIT2**

I tried to compare the payload between my request and GraphiQL request:

My request's payload: ( it has `__typename` which I don't know why )

```
{"operationName":"getStudents","variables":{"schoolID":1},"query":"query getStudents($schoolID: Int) {\n  allStudents(schoolId: $schoolID) {\n    pickUpLat\n    pickUpLng\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}
```

GraphiQL request's payload:

```
{"query":"query getStudents($schoolID: Int!){\n  allStudents(schoolId: $schoolID){\n    pickUpLat\n    pickUpLng\n  }\n}","variables":{"schoolID":1},"operationName":"getStudents"}
```

So, they are almost identical, Any idea?

Comment: your variable is `schoolId` and in query it is `$schoolID` this might be the problem

Comment: I found that it should be `schoolID` not `schoolId` , I also tried `$schoolID` but got the same error, kindly see the EDIT above, it show that `schoolID` is the right var name at QUERY VARIABLES section.. how can I get more details on the error?

Comment: What version of `apollo-client` are you using? You're supposed to configure the client with a cache, like `apollo-cache-inmemory`, and normally your client would throw an error if you tried to use it without having done so

Comment: I found that my problem was related to https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/issues/609

Answer (score 12):

The fault with my query was that I didn't download the new schema.

You can download the schema by using: `apollo schema:download --endpoint=http://localhost:8080/graphql schema.json`

replace http://localhost:8080/graphql with your server endpoint

You can see more at '[Apollo - Downloading schema](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/code-generation/downloading-schema/)'

Comment: this it outdated link

Comment: @hellvisor I updated the link

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had defined a query which didn't require any parameters and it would return an array of objects:

```
myBasicQuery: [BasicAnswer]

type BasicAnswer {
  name String
  phone String
}
```

I was getting the error: `Cannot query field \"BasicAnswer\" on type \"BasicAnswer\"` when I declared it like this:

```
query myBasicQuery {
  BasicAnswer {
      name
      phone
  }
}
```

Leaving only the fields of BasicAnswer fixed the issue:

```
query myBasicQuery {
    name
    phone
}
```

Comment: I am not using Apollo.  I am using the fetch API and this answer worked for me. Thank you Lucio!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who might be searching for this problem, make sure you're importing **`ApolloClient`** from **`apollo-client`** package and not other packages.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that follows apollo-client has now been sunset, in favour of [@apollo/client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/apollo-client-3-migration/#apollo-client)

Here is how you should be [constructing a query](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#caching-query-results)

Answer (score 0):

Updated `@graphql-codegen/cli` package to latest version(2.6.2) and it's working fine.

For anybody who use hasura also.

Problem was

````
  query: query_root
  # query: Query # wrong value before upgrade
  mutation: mutation_root
  subscription: subscription_root
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your entity, it may be missing the @Field() annotation.
Example:

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: string;//Will not be mapped by GraphQL and you will get OP's error
    
@Column()
@Field()
name: string;//Will be mapped by GraphQL and you will not get OP's error
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happens, if you have fragmented your graphqls files and you forgot to define it in codegen.ts.

(java-project)/src/main/resources:

- schema.graphqls
- search.graphqls

(angular-project)/codegen.ts

```
const codegen: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  // add wildcards here, to read all files:
  schema: "../projectname/src/main/resources/graphql/*.graphqls",
  documents: './src/app/core/graphql/*.ts',
  generates: {
     ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see this issue in the GraphiQL interface, you may need to merely refresh the page, which downloads the new schema and the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

For those with this issue as of gql 16.7 using strapi v4 (could be earlier versions too, I don't know), the query format wasn't structured correctly. You'll need to update the query to the following:

```
query getStudents {
  allStudents {
    data {
      attributes {
        pickUpLat
        pickUpLng
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Not tested, but you can probably add the query paramaters. Those might need to be adjusted.